# Gaussian Process , selecting the hyperparameters

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, hyperparameter

I am using Gaussian Process regression toolbox from the site  http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/

I was able to use implement the code in matlab easily, following the guide lines. However I am unable to get a coo-relation coefficient  value.

I have a training data set with n=64 and d=5. I use the following mean, covariance and likelihood functions.The testing data set is with n=30, d=6.

```
mean = {@meanPoly ,2}; hyp.mean = [1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
cov = {'covSEiso'};ell=1/4, sf=1 hyp.cov = log ([ell;sf])
lik = @likGauss; sn = 0.1; hyp.lik = log(sn)
```

Then using minimize function as in demoregression provided

```
hyp = minimize(hyp, @gp, -50, @infExact, mean, cov, lik, x, y);
[ymu ys2 fmu fs2 lp] = gp(hyp, @infExact, mean, cov, lik, x, y, xs, ys)
```

I have tried varying the hyper parameters manually but its time consuming and hasn't led to any fruitful results till now.

I would really appreciate if you could show me error I am making in implementing the code.